# extracting just page text using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xml-parsing, html-agility-pack

Ok so i am really new to XPath queries used in HTMLAgilityPack.

So lets consider this page http://health.yahoo.net/articles/healthcare/what-your-favorite-flavor-says-about-you. What i want is to extract just the page content and nothing else.

So for that i first remove script and style tags.

```
Document = new HtmlDocument();
        Document.LoadHtml(page);
        TempString = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (HtmlNode style in Document.DocumentNode.Descendants("style").ToArray())
        {
            style.Remove();
        }
        foreach (HtmlNode script in Document.DocumentNode.Descendants("script").ToArray())
        {
            script.Remove();
        }
```

After that i am trying to use //text() to get all the text nodes.

```
foreach (HtmlTextNode node in Document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()"))
        {
            TempString.AppendLine(node.InnerText);
        }
```

However not only i am not getting just text i am also getting numerous /r /n characters.

Please i require a little guidance in this regard.

Comment: if you want only specific data, you need say from which note, because you take text from everywhere.

Comment: @Darka Basically i am trying to build a webcrawler for my search engine. So i want to basically get useful text from anywhere in the webpage, In Particular i would like to get all the <p> tags for their content value.

Answer (score 16):

If you consider that `script` and `style` nodes only have text nodes for children, you can use this XPath expression to get text nodes that are not in `script` or `style` tags, so that you don't need to remove the nodes beforehand:

```
//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()
```

You can further exclude text nodes that are only whitespace using XPath's `normalize-space()`:

```
//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()[not(normalize-space(.)="")]
```

or the shorter

```
//*[not(self::script or self::style)]/text()[normalize-space()]
```

But you will still get text nodes that may have leading or trailing whitespace. This can be handled in your application as @aL3891 suggests.

Answer (score 2):

If `\r \n` characters in the final string is the problem, you could just remove them after the fact:

```
TempString.ToString().Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
```