# Get website's inner text without webbrowser

Tags: html, vb.net, get, httpwebrequest

I want to get website's inner text through code.

I can already get it's inner html with code below, but i can't find any code that's getting URL's inner text **without webbrowser**.

*This code is getting text from website in webbrowser, but i need same thing, just without webbrowser.*

```
Dim sourceString As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
```

Comment: Do you mean it's opening a webrower and you don't want to use the webbrosers(internet explorer)?

Comment: No, i want to get website's text (not html) through code, without using webbrowser

Comment: Maybe you could use a webbrower that also exports components in an api? If not you'll have to use some socket implementation and most likely also use openssl like thing to hand the https. Then it's just a get request which will return all the html.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net second answer, voted 20 up.

Comment: Are you wanting to collect the readable text rendered in a browser for something like SEO or word count analysis??

Comment: [extracting just page text using HTMLAgilityPack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19343231/1115360) might be useful to you.

Comment: the term you are looking for is "screen scraping". That should lead you to the tools you need

Answer (score 2):

With [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)...

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    Dim doc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    With New Net.WebClient
        doc.LoadHtml(.DownloadString("https://example.com"))
        .Dispose()
    End With

    Debug.Print(doc.DocumentNode.Name)
    PrintChildNodes(doc.DocumentNode)

    Debug.Print(doc.DocumentNode.Element("html").Element("body").InnerText)
End Sub

Sub PrintChildNodes(Node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode, Optional Indent As Integer = 1)
    For Each Child As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In Node.ChildNodes
        Debug.Print("{0}{1}", String.Empty.PadLeft(Indent, vbTab), Child.Name)
        PrintChildNodes(Child, Indent + 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Taken from ** 
[Wolfwyrd](http://Wolfwyrd)

**In this question** [HTTP GET in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net)

```
 Try
Dim fr As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
Dim targetURI As New Uri("http://whatever.you.want.to.get/file.html")         

fr = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(targetURI), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
If (fr.GetResponse().ContentLength > 0) Then
    Dim str As New System.IO.StreamReader(fr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
    Response.Write(str.ReadToEnd())
    str.Close(); 
End If
```

Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
   'Error in accessing the resource, handle it
End Try

You will get Html as well as http headers. Don't think this will work by itself with `https`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that i mentioned TEXT, not html :)